# SimpleDateFormat change date while converting it to Different date format

Tags: java, simpledateformat

I am trying  to convert from  ***YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss***  to  ***dd-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss*** format .

```
String dateToConvert  = "2017-05-05 11:25:58";
SimpleDateFormat source = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"); 
SimpleDateFormat target = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss");
String newDate = target.format(source.parse(dateToConvert));
```

newDate variable value is  "01-01-2017 11:25:58" , which is different from original date.
So which method would work for me?

Comment: Use `yyyy` instead of `YYYY`. `Y` is "week year".

Comment: Thanks it worked for me :)

Comment: Any reason why you are trying to use the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class? [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) is so much nicer to work with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The letter for year is small y

This

```
SimpleDateFormat source = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"); 
SimpleDateFormat target = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss");
```

should be

```
SimpleDateFormat source = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"); 
SimpleDateFormat target = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
```

For future reference see [java doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Answer (score 1):

Better use java 8 Formatters for better perf0rmance :)

```
    String dateToConvert = "2017-05-05 11:25:58";
    DateTimeFormatter source = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    DateTimeFormatter target = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    String newDate = target.format(source.parse(dateToConvert));
```